# How to remove special characters in SQL output

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a dataset with zip codes that end with '-' at the end. What is the most effective way to remove those dashes?

```
SELECT
client.zipcode
FROM CLIENT
```

example output: 21354-

Comment: Replace (update) with regex and only accept numbers could be useful

Comment: [REPLACE (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: What makes most sense is to change your inserts to add them as 21354, not as 21354-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue by adding the following:

```
SUBSTRING (client.zipcode, 1,5) AS zipcode
```

that remove the dashes from the end of the zip codes.

Comment: Assuming all zip codes have 5 digits. That depends on the nature of them (short vs long format) and the country.

Comment: Yes, all of the zip codes have the 5 digit format (short format)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Replace` and replace nothing with '-' as follows:

```
SELECT
    REPLACE(client.Zipcode, '-', '') AS 'Zipcode'
FROM
    Client
```